# Continous function with one of ranges as an equation

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

I'm pretty new here and my formatting might have some errors, sorry I could get it only this far.

f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\ ax+2b,  & x<0 \\[3ex]
\ x^2 + 3a -b, & x^2 + 3a -b \\
\ 3x-5,   &  x > 2 \\
\end{cases}

The question here is 
"if following function is continuous for every x, what are the values unknowns a and b  can get?"

I know that for a function to be continuous it has to have a limit and not skip any points etc so "x^2+3a-b" should cover the range between 2 and 0, but I don't know the exact solution nor how do I validate this(if someone has a way of putting this into wolframalpha, please do tell, or even any form of continuity so I can validate my answers)

The method I am most sure about  is for point "0" I can put 0 instead of x and it has to be equal to the second formula, and I can then put "2" instead of "x" in second and third formula and try to get something from there, but I don't know the exact solution nor the answer.

If someone knows how can I solve this and by doing what I can do the math so I don't expect you guys to solve it completely but I simply don't know the path I should take.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you be more clear? What do you mean with c? Are you suggesting that I try to make function equal to something like i^2 + ij + k ? so a*0 + 2b = i^2 + ij + k and 3*2 - 5 = i^2 + ij + k so (i^2 + ij + k = 1) and 2b is 1 so b is 1/2... I think  I'm lost.

Comment: Can you please make the definition of your function $f$ clearer... the second line doesnt make any sense... Do you mean, that $f(x)=x^2+3a-b$ for $0\leq x\leq 2$?

Comment: This is the question I have in front of me, I wouldn't completely eliminate maybe someone made a mistake preparing the question? But this is the exact form I have the question on.

Comment: Then there must be some mistake, because on the right hand side in the second line there should be a statement like $0\leq x\leq 2$ or $x^2+3a-b<17$ or so. But at the moment there is just a term... Are you really sure you havent overlooked something?

Comment: Yes I'm but as you said the question might be incorrect. here is the exact part of paper: http://i.imgur.com/RZfQxzd.png Can you tell me what would I do if it said x^2 +3a -b < 17 ? Thanks ^_^

Comment: That was just an example of a statement without sense ;)
I am pretty sure it must be $x^2+3a-b$ for $0\leq x\leq 2$, because only then the function is even well posed. And in this case you can use @user58697's idea

Comment: Oh! I see. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as you planned: Plugging 0 for $x$, you'd get $2b = 3a - b$. Plugging 2 for $x$, you'd also get $4 + 3a - b = 1$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you. If this is the proper solution and not a shortcut for something we normally do other ways and this is just happens to work here, this is what I wanted! :) Thank you. Also the other folk said something along the lines of "use quadratic formula" and deleted his first comment and replied to my comment saying "you are correct", do you know whats up with that?